# C++ multithreading application crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, dictionary, vector

I'm programming a simple 3D rendering engine just to get more familliar with C++. Today I had my first steps with multithreading and already have a problem I cannot wrap my head around. When the application starts it generates a small, minecraft-like terrain consisting of cubes. They're generated withhin the main thread.

**Now when I want to generate more chunks**

```
void VoxelWorld::generateChunk(glm::vec2 chunkPosition) {
    Chunk* generatedChunk = m_worldGenerator->generateChunk(chunkPosition);
    generatedChunk->shader = m_chunkShader;
    generatedChunk->generateRenderObject();
    m_chunks[chunkPosition.x][chunkPosition.y] = generatedChunk;
    m_loadedChunks.push_back(glm::vec2(chunkPosition.x, chunkPosition.y));
}

void VoxelWorld::generateChunkThreaded(glm::vec2 chunkPosition) {
    std::thread chunkThread(&VoxelWorld::generateChunk, this, chunkPosition);
    chunkThread.detach();
}

void VoxelWorld::draw() {
    for(glm::vec2& vec : m_loadedChunks){
        Transformation* transformation = new Transformation();
        transformation->getPosition().setPosition(glm::vec3(CHUNK_WIDTH*vec.x, 0, CHUNK_WIDTH*vec.y));
        m_chunks[vec.x][vec.y]->getRenderObject()->draw(transformation);
        delete(transformation); //TODO: Find a better way
    }
}
```

I have my member function (everything is non-static) `generateChunk()` which generates a Chunk and stores it in the `VoxelWorld` class. I have a 2D `std::map<..> m_chunks` which stores every chunk and a `std::vector<glm::vec2> m_loadedChunks` which stores the positions of the generated chunks.

Calling `generateChunk()` works fine as expected. But when I try `generateChunkThreaded()` the application crashes! I tried commenting out the last line of `generateChunk()`, then it does not crash. Thats what confuses me so much! `m_loadedChunks` ist just a regular std::vector. I tried making it public, with no effect. Is there anything obvious I miss?

Comment: I can't spot even the tiniest attempt at synchronising access to `m_chunks` or `m_loadedChunks`.

Comment: Also, avoid dynamic allocation in your drawing loop.

Comment: @molbdnilo Is that a big problem? I mean how does it matter in that case? `m_loadedChunks` has no specific order and `m_chunks` is a map with many maps. My draw call is a mess, I'm aware of that. Thats on my TODO list.

Comment: Where are you learning multithreaded programming from? You should probably get yourself better study materials.

Comment: The internet. I've never had anything better.

Comment: By the way, if you would like an excellent resource on C++ concurrency, you should follow Herb Sutter's articles. Here's a video of him giving a presentation on multithreaded programming: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing m_loadedChunks from several threads without synchronizing it.
You need to lock the usage of shared usages. So few tips here.

1. Declare a mutex as a member of the class

> ```
> std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section
> ```

2. Use it to lock via a critical section each time you want to access the elements

> std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
>
> m_chunks[chunkPosition.x][chunkPosition.y] = generatedChunk;
>
> m_loadedChunks.push_back(glm::vec2(chunkPosition.x, chunkPosition.y));

Hope that helps

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll try that. But why do I have to lock it?

Comment: @Kiryu144 1. there is too little code here to narrow down exactly what is crashing your program. A lack of concurrency defence is a obvious problem that if it isn't the cause of your current bug, will be a future problem. 2. Use the mutex, but [use it with a `std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) so you get scoped unlocking and fewer nasty surprises.  To be continued....

Comment: 3. Why do you need this? Here is one reason: `m_loadedChunks.push_back` may resize `m_loadedChunks`'s backing datastore while another thread is iterating it. Part of resizing is deleting and replacing the old data store, so the data this other thread is looking at may have just vanished. It has been replaced by a copy, but the other thread has no way of knowing this.

Comment: You are right, this are the first steps of the resolution of the problem. Right for lock_guard, I will ammend my code

Comment: Well, thats true, but I only indent to use threading for the terrain generation. At least for now. I don't know if its appropriate, but there would be the [link](https://bitbucket.org/Kiryu144/amethyst3d/src/b65d8ee030a05501b70b67c8680f303f42ef1f01/source/game/?at=master) to bitbucket. There you can also see my header file. I'm currently crushing my head with this friggin bug! **EDIT** This is with without actual use of mutex.

Answer (score 0):

When you have many threads access shared resources, you either have those resources available as read-only, atomic, or guarded with a mutex lock.

So, for your m_loadedChunks member variable, you would want to have it wrapped in a lock. For example:

```
class VoxelWorld
{
    // your class members and more ...
private:
  std::mutex m_loadedChunksMutex;
}

void VoxelWorld::generateChunk(glm::vec2 chunkPosition)
{
    Chunk* generatedChunk  = m_worldGenerator->generateChunk(chunkPosition);
    generatedChunk->shader = m_chunkShader;

    generatedChunk->generateRenderObject();

    m_chunks[chunkPosition.x][chunkPosition.y] = generatedChunk;

    {
        auto&& scopedLock = std::lock_guard< std::mutex >(m_loadedChunksMutex);
        (void)scopedLock;
        m_loadedChunks.push_back(glm::vec2(chunkPosition.x, chunkPosition.y));
    }
}
```

The scopedLock will automatically wait for a lock and when the code goes out of scope, the lock will be released.

**Now note**, that I have a mutex for **m_loadedChunks** and not a generic mutex covering all variables that may be accessed by threads. This is actually a good practice introduced by Herb Sutter in his "Effective Concurrency" courses and on his talks at cppcon.

So, for whatever shared variables you have, use the above example as one means to solve race issues.